# Redirect when a ViewExpiredException is thrown within ajax request

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, omnifaces

I have a problem with the handling of `ViewExpiredExceptions` within ajax requests.
In my special case it is a `rich:datascroller` which makes problems. I use omnifaces 1.8.1's `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` to handle VEEs thrown by Ajax components.

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/my/pages/error/viewExpired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

viewExpired.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewExpiredHandler.handle}" />
</html>
```

And the Java Class:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ViewExpiredHandler {

    public void handle() {
                String outcome = "/path/to/home.xhtml";
                //Version 1 *************
             try {
                ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                String redir = ec.getRequestContextPath() + outcome;
                ec.redirect(redir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ...
            }
                //Version 2 ************
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        fc.setViewRoot(fc.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(fc, outcome));
        fc.getPartialViewContext().setRenderAll(true);
        fc.renderResponse();
        }
}
```

If the session expires and the I click on a datascroller button I see my handle() method gets invoked but the forwarding to the home page doesn't work.

With Version 1 nothing happens at all, with version 2 I first get a blank screen and if I refresh the page with the browser button the handle() method gets invoked again and successfully redirects to the home page

Can you see any error in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect has no effect, because `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` entirely takes over the rendering and JSF thus can't write the ajax redirect to the response. Changing the view has no effect, because the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` has at that moment already the error page view at its hands and won't consult the `FacesContext` for the changed view. You get a blank screen because your error page is blank by itself.

Just let the browser redirect by itself. Make use of JS `window.location`. Replace your entire `viewExpired.xhtml` page with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <script>window.location="#{request.contextPath}/path/to/home.xhtml";</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this solution works  only with Chrome. Firefox and IE 8 (which is actually the only browser I have to support) continue showing a blank page. What I noticed, the html "head" of the blank page is the same as the one where the VEE happened. The application uses servlet Filters which neither change the response nor make sendRedirect(): do I have to check for something else in particular there? Thanks!

Comment: Is your ajax handled by RichFaces? I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: yes it is. And with Javascript redirect works! :) Thank you again!